# IOptions values are not binding in Azure Function app

Tags: c#, configuration, azure-functions

I have a .net 8 isolated function app.

I am injecting `IOptions<TelegramSettings>`, but `settings.Value.Token` is always empty. Can anyone tell me why?

```cs
// Settings class
public class TelegramSettings
{
    public const string ConfigKey = "Telegram";

    [MinLength(1)]
    public string Token { get; set; } = "";
}
```

```cs
// Program.cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddOptions<AuthSettings>(AuthSettings.ConfigKey);
        services.AddSingleton<ITelegramService, TelegramService>();
    }; //etc
```

```cs
// Consuming service
public class TelegramService : ITelegramService
{
    private readonly TelegramBotClient TelegramBotClient;

    public TelegramService(IOptions<TelegramSettings> telegramOptions)
    {
        TelegramBotClient = new TelegramBotClient(telegramOptions.Value.Token);
    }
}
```

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "Telegram": {
    "Token": "sf"
  }, etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Configure` method to register `TelegramSettings` option.

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilder, services) =>
    {
        //NOTE THIS
        services.Configure<TelegramSettings>(a => hostBuilder.Configuration.GetSection("Telegram").Bind(a));

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddOptions<AuthSettings>(AuthSettings.ConfigKey);
        services.AddSingleton<ITelegramService, TelegramService>();
    });
```

Comment: Or just `services.Configure<TelegramSettings>(hostBuilder.Configuration.GetSection("Telegram"))`